# Only print when run as script?

Tags: python, scripting, logging

Is there a better way to only print when run as a script, when `__name__ == '__main__'` ?

I have some scripts that I also import and use parts of.

Something like the below will work but is ugly, and would have to be defined in each script separately:

```
def printif(s):
    if globals()['__name__'] == '__main__':
        print (s)
    return
```

I looked briefly at some of python's logging libraries but would prefer a two lighter solution...

edit:

I ended up doing something like this:

```
# mylog.py
import sys
import logging

log = logging.getLogger()

#default logging level
log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

And from the script:

```
import log from mylog

...
log.info(...)
log.warning(...)
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #override when script is run..
    log.setLevel(logger.INFO)
```

This scheme has minimal code duplication, per script log levels, and a project-wide default level...which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a logging library is really not *that* heavyweight:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('myscript')

def dostuff(...):
    ....
    log.info('message!')
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    ...
```

One wart is the "WARNING: no handlers found for myscript" message  that logging prints by default if you import this module (rather than run it as a script), and call your function without setting up logging.  [It'll be gone](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/12/proposed-changes-to-logging-defaults.html) in Python 3.2.  For Python 2.7, you can shut it off by adding

```
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

at the top, and for older versions you'd have to [define a NullHandler class](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/logging.html#library-config) like this:

```
class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass
```

Looking back at all this, I say: go with Gerrat's suggestion.  I'll leave mine here, for completeness.

Comment: I am using a variation this. Simple logging in python is lightweight (boiler-plate, syntax).

Answer (score 5):

```
run_as_script = False  

def printif(s):  
    if run_as_script:  
        print (s)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    run_as_script = True
```

Comment: This is just alias-ing __name__ == __main__ , and is equivalent to the code I posted above. If this is defined in another module than the script and imported, it does not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In light of user318904's comment on my other answer, I'll provide an alternative (although this may not work in all cases, it might just be "good enough").
For a separate module:

```
import sys

def printif(s):
    if sys.argv[0] != '':
        print (s)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right this does work. I was a hasty in dismissing it. I am still going to opt for more features with the logging package but I will add this to my utility functions..thanks!